# IE8-zoom breaks my layout

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, zooming

i have a problem with my zoom in ie8.

Okay, i have the function where i have 3 buttons. Onclick on those button my webpage get zoomed for the value that stands behind that button. All is saved into a cookie and onload of the page this cookie is loaded and the css property is set throughout the entire page.

My JS-Code:

```
    var content = document.getElementById("zoomable");
document.getElementById('zoomable').style.zoom = myvalue;
document.getElementById('zoomable').style.overflow = "auto";
content.style.overflow = "auto";
document.getElementById('zoomable').style.MozTransform = 'scale('+myvalue+')';
document.getElementById('zoomable').style.MozTransformOrigin = '0 0';
document.cookie="mysize=" + myvalue;
```

Everything is okay in Chrome, IE9, IE7 (at least it seems like it is okay there, i may be wrong) and FF. In ie8 this function destroys my layout. It seems like the zoom function rezizes everything instead of just zooming in. It breaks through the borders to the right and creates a nasty overflow that isn't even scrollable. I searched and tried and tried and searched but without any success.

Does anyone know the problem? (if it is not clear, what i mean by all that feel free to ask :) )

so far
Adi

edit:
If it is important, i might add, that my layout isn't made of tables but created with divs with the "display-table:" prop

edit2:

Okay i got it.

If someone had the same problem, i show i my personal mistake.

my div for the "zoomable" property which is my body tag:

```
margin: 10px auto;
width: 974px;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 0 12px 5px 12px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 11px;
```

Now the problem is, that ie8 changed the scaling of the page width by impossible ammounts. So i used a div to wrap everything inside the body tag and gave all those atributes above to the new div and removed the older ones from the body tag. I didn't change anything in my jquery, i still use the zoom on the body tag or else i get the same problem as before.
I don't know what is causing this beheivor.. It is only in the ie8.
But thanks anyways for everyone who had read this! :D